# TextInput handle emoji Windows 10

Tags: qml

I have TextInput and Label as placeholder. Normaly, when textinput.length > 0, lable placeholder hide. When user press Windows + ; show emoji popup and select, I can't handle event.

```
Label
{
    id: txtPlaceHolder
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.leftMargin: textInputLeftMargin
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
    verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
    color: placeholderColor
    font.pixelSize: fontSize
    visible: txtContent.text.length == 0
}
TextInput
{
    id: txtContent
    anchors.fill: parent
    font.pixelSize: fontSize
    selectionColor: root.selectionColor

    font.bold: fontBold
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: txtContent.forceActiveFocus()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: When user select emoji fill to TextInput, TextInput still length = 0 and I can't hide txtPlaceHolder.